# How to remove UEFI supervisor password? Acer Aspire 771G

Tags: boot, bios, passwords, uefi, acer-aspire

2 years ago I try to install a Linux distribution.
 - To do so I need to  disable  the secure boot and set the supervisor password.
 - My keyboard was giving me problems at that time and now i don't know the password.
 - I need it in order to change the boot options.
 - I tried everything to remove the password.
a. I quit the battery, short the jumpers,  it doesn't give a code to disable the password.
b. the last thing I did was to edit the bios update so i can remove that but i have the last update installed, now i can't do a downgrade and this file  when i run it, it reset the changes that I made.

> can someone help me.

Comment: If you have attempted to remove the password using the steps you describe, and you do not know the password to otherwise change the password, then the password cannot be removed.  The entire point of the password is the prevent unauthorized changes, if it was easy to remove without knowing the password, then it wouldn't offer any protection.  In other words you are out of luck.  Worth pointing out you can install Linux with Secure Boot enabled (but the boot order is sort of a deal breaker)

Comment: Well, I was thinking that maybe if the bios password could be removed that easy, I could do it with the uefi too. Now I know that it is not. thanks Ramhound